# Response notification date range getting shorter?

Tags: discussion, notifications, notification-bar, dates

Sometimes when I click on the header link telling me I have X responses, I get no responses. I noticed the date range is 4 days only. I thought it was 90 days. Yeah I guess the range is getting shorter so the query doesn't time out with the increasing size of the database.

Why doesn't SO save the date of the oldest response and use it in the date range as the start date, specially when that date is not far off? SO already saves some info about the responses for me so might as well save that date and make the function work better instead of showing nothing. My guess it's not that important a feature to save extra data in the database?

(I know how to get those responses)